# Regular Expression in Java which will find occurrence of `I` except when `ARTICLE I` comes

Tags: java, regex

I want one regular expression which will find occurrence of `I` from string

But ignore `I` when `ARTICLE I` comes or `ARTICLE III` comes

I made regular expression but it counts occurrence when `ARTICLE I` comes

```
(?:(^I[ ]|[ ]I[, ]|[ ]I$|(!ARTICLE[ ]I+$)))
```

Except this it works well in all cases even for `ARTICLE III` also

Comment: Can you just extract "ARTICLE III" out of the way and do the matching?

Comment: It was a pain removing the titlecase!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [negative lookbehind](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html): `(?<!ARTICLE )(\bI+\b)` (not sure what exactly you want to capture but this should get you started.)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the token that comes after the `ARTICLE` is Roman numeral. So this is my solution:

```
String s = "KSLJFI ARTICLE III SPIOEWF ARTICLE I ASDKJHJK OSDIF ARTICLE IV SKDJFHJSOIFPOEIF";
String temp = s.replaceAll("ARTICLE\\s+\\b[IVXLCDM]+\\b", "");
```

You can match any `I` in the temporary string without worrying that it will match the `I` in `ARTICLE` or `I` in Roman numeral.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s="ARTICLE II";
    String[] ss=s.split("(\\s+)I+");

    for(int i=0;i<ss.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(ss[i]);
    }
}
```